# Crashing when trying to parse a hex string

Tags: c

I have a `hex` string in the form of "404C49474854" .
I am trying to extract the text string out of it with :

```
void  textFromHexString(char *hex,char *result)
{

    for(int k=1;k<strlen(hex);k+=2)
    {
         char temp[3]={0};
        sprintf(temp,"%c%c",hex[k-1],hex[k]);
        *result=char((int)strtol(temp, NULL, 16));
         result++;
        *result ='\0';
         print(temp);   //**** edit

    }

}
```

I call it from inside another function, with :

```
void somefunction()
{
            // I have p here, which prints "404C49474854"
           char text[TEXT_MAX_SIZE]={0};
            textFromHexString(p,text);
}
```

It works, but **it works 80% of the time**. in some cases it crashes, where :

-incoming `hex` pointer is : `"404C49474854"`. *for sure .*

-where the pointer `temp` get a completely other values that are not even inside `hex`.

Is there something basically wrong with this method ?

**EDIT:**
Check where the line that prints inside the loop, it will print this in a very specific situation :

```
4Hello, world
```

How `temp`, that consist of numbers only, gets this string ? (the "Hello world", is just a string I print at the beginning of the program, also temp size is 3)

Comment: You know that array indexing starts from `[0]`? So `for(int k=1; ...` should be `for(int k=0; ...`

Comment: No, since they do `hex[k-1]`.

Comment: No, its not. I am starting from index-1. read it.

Comment: Oh mybad, contorted code.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think he's good on that, because he subtracts one on indexing.

Comment: What is `TEST_MAX_SIZE`?

Comment: Is max size long enough for null terminator?

Comment: Thanks its much larger then the incoming. its 25. I just can't get this. struggling for 3 hours, since the incoming string is ok, and it won't even finish the loop, so its crashing inside it.

Comment: By the way, you're mixing C and C++. The expression `char(...)` is a C++ type-cast. It's not a valid C expression.

Comment: As for your problem, have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger? Where in your code does it crash? What are the values of all involved variables and macros?

Comment: I ran the code, and it executed without any errors, even after considering the edit. Maybe some aspect of the code not shown in the question is responsible?

Comment: Thanks , see my edit , It crashes where I print temp, that gets a large string that is not related to anything..

Comment: Could you give us [enough code to actually compile it](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler because the code runs on a chip that cannot handle sscanf...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, I do not have to tell you what my constrains are, or where I came from. This is the code that I am trying to solve, and lets stay specific about it. Please don't get med just because you do not have answer.

Comment: At the risk of furthering the flamethrower, is there a *specific* reason  `char temp[] = { hex[k-1], hex[k], 0 };` is not used, and thusly throwing out your `sscanf` madness ? Unrelated (likely) to your problem, but the purist in me cannot see the sense in using a sledgehammer to drive a pushpin.

Comment: Thats because you don't use hardware. Things are different when you programing C into hardware with limited resources. You can not do what ever you want , like you do in an online compiler or a pc. sscanf is not accepted in most of the hardware chips when programing in C, for performance reasons.

Comment: I concur (about your `sscanf` assessment; not about the "you don't use hardware" bullshit; your arrogance in presuming to know what I've done in 30 years in this industry is laughable). I wouldn't use `sscanf` either. My question is, when an initializer would do what you appear to be trying, and avoid a library call in the process. `char temp[] = { hex[k-1], hex[k], 0 };` why not do it?. No, its not an answer to your post, but that's why I put it here, not below. If there is some reason for doing what you are, great. I was simply asking, so how about simply answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sscanf()` to directly read hexadecimal numbers of a given length, like so:

```
while(hex[0] && hex[1]) {
  int value;
  sscanf(hex, "%2x", &value);
  printf("%c", value);
  hex += 2;
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: The question was whether there is something wrong with their code, not what would work instead.

Comment: I can't and its not the question here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if most errors were found by the commenters, so here is code that works under the assumption that I guessed right what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!

void textFromHexString(char *hex, char result[])
{
  // work on copy
  char *p = result;

  // this has more steps than necessary for clarity
  for (size_t k = 1; k < strlen(hex); k += 2) {
    // normalize input
    char first = tolower(hex[k - 1]);
    char second = tolower(hex[k]);
    // convert hexbyte to decimal number
    int f1 = (isdigit(first)) ? first - '0' : (first - 'a') + 10;
    int f2 = (isdigit(second)) ? second - '0' : (second - 'a') + 10;
    // two byte number from LSB hex to decimal (e.g.: "ab" = 171)
    int num = f1 * 16 + f2;
    // needs to store min. 3 characters plus NUL
    char temp[4] = { 0 };
    // sprintf is a bit too much for it but simple
    sprintf(temp, "%d", num);
    // concatenate temp to the result-string
    strcat(p, temp);
    // For debugging, I guess, or further work?
    printf("%s\n", temp);
  }
}

#define TEXT_MAX_SIZE 64
int main()
{
  // 0x404C49474854 = 70696391100500
  char *p = "404C49474854";
  // allocate some scratchspace on the stack
  char text[TEXT_MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };

  textFromHexString(p, text);
  // the function textFromHexString() does it in chunks of two bytes,
  // so the result is 647673717284 here
  printf("Result: %s\n", text);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: The question was whether there is something wrong with their code, not what would work instead.

Comment: What is that? a very long version to do the exact same thing? My code runs and works that for sure, but for the last 5 hours I am trying to understand why it crashes at a certain point even when the input is valid and good.

Comment: @Curnelious main differences: it does not crash and works with your input. It is not possible to give you the exact reason why your code crashes because your are not willing and/or able to give the necessary details. Might be a crappy compiler, broken hardware (you hinted at "embeded"), that `TEXT_MAX_SIZE` is of insufficient size or that a negative 2-digit number plus NUL does not  fit into `temp[3]`.

Comment: If it is not possible to answer a question, maybe you should *not answer it* and write a comment asking for clarification. (Or downvote, flag, move along, whatever…)

Comment: @HermannDöppes there were questions for clarifications already and they were denied an answer. The OP might have some good reasons to do so, I do not know them. So I posted that commented code such that the OP can compare and hopefuly find their error themself.